# NSMutableArray in PList keeps replacing previous NSMutableArray when added to to PList

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, plist, ios4

I know this is an easy one, but I just started working with plists, and I am having trouble. I can write the Array to the plist no problem, but when I try to add a second array it just replaces the previous one.

Here's the code:

```
self.excersizeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4];
    [excersizeArray addObject:excersizeName];
    [excersizeArray addObject:numSets];
    [excersizeArray addObject:time];
    [excersizeArray addObject:restTime];
self.excersizesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:20];
    [excersizesArray addObject:excersizeArray];
```

Here is the plist:

[image]

Comment: Could you describe what you want the plist to look like?

Comment: Exactly like above. An array of arrays, I realized I can't append plists.... that was my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `NSMutableArray` method `addObjectsFromArray:` to add the contents of the array rather than the array itself. For example,

```
self.excersizeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4];
    [excersizeArray addObject:excersizeName];
    [excersizeArray addObject:numSets];
    [excersizeArray addObject:time];
    [excersizeArray addObject:restTime];
self.excersizesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:20];
    [excersizesArray addObjectsFromArray:excersizeArray];
```

All I've changed is the last line. This will add the contents of the array rather than the array itself.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I'm very new to obj-c. I did that, but it's still replacing the previous array (item 0) instead of adding it to item 1 in the plist.

Comment: @novicePrgrmr Once you call `[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4]`, there is no first object. The array is empty. What do you expect the first object to be?

Comment: Sorry, I realized there is no append method for plists. So I am just going to read the plist, add the new array to the, and write everything back in. I think that's the right way to go about it but let me know if there's a better way. Thanks!